# Create a list of numbers dividable by certain numbers by using the command « filter() »

Tags: python, filter

I’m on Python) I have to use filter()  to create a list of all numbers from 1 to 100 (inclusive) that are dividable by 7, 9 and 42. I wrote this code, however, when I start it, it does not give me the right solutions. Do you know where the problem is ?

```
listnumbers = []
for x in range (1, 101):
    x = str(x)
    listnumbers.append(x)
print (listnumbers)

def dividable(k):
    for t in k:
        if int(t) % 7 == 0:
            return True
        if int(t) % 9 == 0:
            return True
        if int(t) % 42 == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return dividable

s2u = list(filter(dividable, listnumbers))

for q in s2u:
    print(q)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are converting your numbers to strings? Is that a requirement?

Comment: What is `return dividable` supposed to do? For that matter, are you aware that your `for` loop will only execute a single iteration?

Comment: No, i tried to correct the errors indicated, but i maybe messed up the code..

Comment: I don’t really know... they told us to put it to « end » a function

Comment: The function you pass to `filter` should take a single value (the number) and return `True` or `False`. You don't need a `for` loop in there.

Comment: Ok, but with the for loop am I not analyzing value by value?

Comment: No, `filter()` passes each value in the list to the function one by one.

Comment: Okok, so i have to remove this for loop and just put the if conditions?

Comment: But it will still not work with the numbers converted to strings like you're doing. Right now, your list contains strings like "42", which is not divisible by 7, 9, 42 or by any other integer, and in fact it is an error to try.

Answer (score 0):

Just eyeballing your code, I think `dividable(k)` is not written correctly.  Update to :

```
def dividable(k):
    n = int(k)
    return n % 7 == 0 or n % 9 == 0 or n % 42 == 0:
```

Why was there a for look declared in this method?  And why was it returning the function at the end if it passed through the rest of the conditions?

Comment: You mean the meaning of the word ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem statement the number should be divisible by 7 **and** 9 **and** 42.

```
listnumbers = list(range(1,101))

def dividable(k):
    if k % 7 == 0 and k % 9 == 0 and k % 42 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

ans = list(filter(dividable, listnumbers))
print(ans)
```

Comment: I think you probably want `or` not `and`.